# Inno-Setup update HKCU of original user in Win7/Vista

Tags: ms-access-2007, inno-setup

I'm trying to add my application path as a Trusted Location for an MS Access install using Inno Setup.  I have the following lines in my script:

```
[Registry]
; Add the application folder as a trusted location for Access 2007
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: string; ValueName: Path; ValueData: {app}; Check: AccessVersion('2007');
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: string; ValueName: Description; ValueData: Grandjean and Braverman applications; Check: AccessVersion('2007');
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: dword; ValueName: AllowSubfolders; ValueData: 1; Check: AccessVersion('2007');
```

This works fine in Windows XP and earlier, but often fails under User Account Control in Vista/Win7 because the (elevated) user running the install may be different than the currently logged in user.

The only workaround I can think of is to have a .reg file that gets extracted and run via `ShellExecAsOriginalUser`, but this seems hackish.  Is there a better way?

Ideally, I would like the trusted location to be added for all users on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the [command-line utility `reg.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true) to do updates to the original user's HKCU.  `Reg.exe` has shipped with Windows since at least Win XP.  Since earlier versions of Windows may not have `reg.exe` (or it may not be accessible for some other reason), I've left the Registry section lines in place to provide redundancy and fallback.

It's still a bit hackish, but I think it is better than any of the other alternatives.  Here's how the lines from the question look with this approach:

```
[Registry]
; Add the application folder as a trusted location for Access 2007 for the installing user (degrades gracefully for Windows 2000 and earlier)
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: string; ValueName: Path; ValueData: {app}; Check: AccessVersion('2007');
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: string; ValueName: Description; ValueData: Grandjean and Braverman applications; Check: AccessVersion('2007');
Root: HKCU; SubKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}; ValueType: dword; ValueName: AllowSubfolders; ValueData: 1; Check: AccessVersion('2007');

[Run]
; Add the application folder as a trusted location for Access 2007 for the current user
Filename: Reg.exe; Parameters: "add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}"" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d ""{app}"" /f"; Flags: runasoriginaluser; Check: AccessVersion('2007'); StatusMsg: Adding trusted location...
Filename: Reg.exe; Parameters: "add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}"" /v Description /t REG_SZ /d ""Grandjean and Braverman applications"" /f"; Flags: runasoriginaluser; Check: AccessVersion('2007'); StatusMsg: Adding trusted location...
Filename: Reg.exe; Parameters: "add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\{#DirName}"" /v AllowSubfolders /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f"; Flags: runasoriginaluser; Check: AccessVersion('2007'); StatusMsg: Adding trusted location...
```

Notice that the lines have been copied and modified from the `[Registry]` section to the `[Run]` section and have the flag `runasoriginaluser` set.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your particular case is to create a second setup which does not require elevated privileges, just to update the registry.

You can include this second setup executable inside the first one and call it with the /verysilent command line parameter using the already mentioned ShellExecuteAsOriginalUser.

For your second question, you must post it as a different question, I'm not access expert, but maybe you can do a whole-machine configuration adding the same values to the HKLM registry key.

My 5 cents.

Comment: Good thought on the second installer.  As for doing the whole machine, I've considered looping through the HKEY_USERS hive and just adding the lines for every user.  I already have plenty of pascal scripting in my installer, but I am by no means an expert so I'm not sure if that approach would even be possible.

Comment: @mwolfe02: AFAIK enumerating `HKEY_USERS` will only give you user hives that are loaded at that exact moment. It won't give you access to hives that are "dormant" from users that currently not logged on.

Comment: @Oliver:  That's good to know.  If that's the case, there's not much point in trying to enumerate the HKU hive.  In any case, I'm fairly pleased with my current workaround (using `reg.exe` and `runasoriginaluser`) and will probably just stick with that for the foreseeable future.